# How to set the bold font of the keyword Definition using IEEEtran without introducing package ntheorem?

Tags: fonts, theorems, ieeetran, ntheorem

I am writing a paper with the recommended template `IEEEtran.sty`. IEEEtran has its own theorem environment such as definitions, theorems, axioms, corollaries, lemmas, and so on. 
I want to set the bold font of the keywords `Definition` and `Theorem`. I know how to do this with the package `ntheorem`. However, I do not want to introduce this package into the `IEEEtran` template (avoiding possible side effects). Thus,

> How can I set the bold font of the keywords `Definition` and `Theorem` using "IEEEtran.sty" without introducing package "ntheorem"?

Edit from comment: I write the code `\documentclass[10pt,conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}` and `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`.

Comment: The standard IEEEtran class defines the theorem names to be bold. So maybe you need an update? By the way, if you submit this to IEEE journal don't do such modifications.

Comment: @percusse I am using IEEEtran V1.8 downloaded from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) about a week ago. So it should be the latest. I simply put the file `IEEEtran.cls` in the same folder with my `.tex` source file. I write the code `\documentclass[10pt,conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}` and `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`. Did I miss something important?

Comment: Not that I can see but here is the output from writelatex https://www.writelatex.com/219094gjxmfg The theorem caption comes out bold.

Comment: Thx. It now works when I use package `amsthm` as you suggested in writelatex. However, the numbering of theorem is now in Roman like IV.2. Is it typical? How can I change it back to the Arabic numbering like 4.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if you are being asked to use a standard template then you should not change the defaults.

Otherwise, there are two approaches.

## Approach 1

In `IEEEtran` version v1.8a, theorem titles are italic by default, unless you use the `compsoc` option, which gives a bold italic title.  If you add this option then a minimal document with a theorem gives the following, but as you see the formatting of sections is also changed.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[conference,compsocconf,compsoc,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

## Approach 2

You can patch the theorem making command `\@begintheorem` to replace `\textit` by `\textbf` as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\textit}{\textbf}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass[conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\textit}{\textbf}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```